# Error on Buffering Stream Swift MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, buffering

in my streaming application built in Swift and using MPMoviePlayerController as default player, I'm trying to identify the cases when the video has buffering error issues and get a notification related to them. I tried all the MPMoviePlayerController Playback and Load States but none of them seems to work. Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated iOS9 onwards. What iOS version are you running the application on ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller